# What data type am I going to use when passing an array of integers in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpDelete]
public JsonResult ReservationCancel(int[] reservationId)
{
    var model = ReservationDAO.getReservation(reservationId);
    return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Im trying to pass Id (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) , I am going to delete all of these Ids

What am I going to put in my jquery ajax data and contenttype?, if im only passing an array of number?

```
.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  url: '/Dashboard/Reservation',
  data: { reservationId: Id },
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) {
}
```

Comment: You realise your method is expecting a `DELETE` and you're sending it a `POST`, right?

Comment: `data: { reservationId: [1,2,3,4] },`, add `traditional: true,` and remove `contentType: 'application/json',` and change the method attribute to `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use content-Type as "appliaction/json" then you can parse the data as:

```
JSON.stringify({ reservationId: Id });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good,

You can send data like this. depending how you get this data at server side, you can change:

```
 data: JSON.stringify( {"reservationId":"[1,2,3,4]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need :

**Method 1**

1) You need to use `JSON.stringify()`

**JSON.stringify function turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores it in a string.**

See reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/Dashboard/Reservation',
    data: JSON.stringify({ reservationId: Id }),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

2)Your controller it should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReservationCancel(string reservationId)
{
   //deserializer reservationId string
   var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   int[] reservationIDs = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(reservationId);
   var model = ReservationDAO.getReservation(reservationIDs);
   return Json(model,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Method 2**

Use `traditional` property for ajax:

```
.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     traditional: true,
     url: '/Dashboard/Reservation',
     data: { reservationId: Id },
     cache: false,
     success: function (data) {

     }
});
```